# Session id using curl_7_35

Tags: curl, ssl

I want to use `curl` to get the session ID. Is there is any way to get the session ID using `curl`? I was using Open SSL to capture the session id before. Now, I don't want to use it.

I tried to send this command:

```shell
curl_7_35_0 -v -k -tls1.2 --sessionid 'not_sure_what_to_use_here' https://30.1.1.101/ssl_ecdhe.txt
```

Am I missing something here? If yes, please do let me know.

Output with OpenSSL is:

```shellsession
Cli31(runs)# /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl s_client -connect 30.1.1.101:443 -tls1_2 -servername 20.1.1.1 -reconnect -crlf

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = A10Networks Inc., OU = QA, CN = www.automationserver.com, emailAddress = info@a10networks.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = A10Networks Inc., OU = QA, CN = www.automationserver.com, emailAddress = info@a10networks.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=A10Networks Inc./OU=QA/CN=www.automationserver.com/emailAddress=info@a10networks.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=A10Networks Inc./OU=QA/CN=www.automationserver.com/emailAddress=info@a10networks.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=A10Networks Inc./OU=QA/CN=www.automationserver.com/emailAddress=info@a10networks.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=A10Networks Inc./OU=QA/CN=www.automationserver.com/emailAddress=info@a10networks.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1010 bytes and written 475 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
drop connection and then reconnect
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Reused, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 0AABABCBB2C24ABD3D5BD4B84A1914EC563E3D518108A89487A6B056BB879CC4
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BCD8B034C67DB603132FB69295FEB996628502A08BE9E58BAF03D365A8FFCC03E117A4D836BB782AAA2D65424686BB2A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1503310272
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
GET /ssl_ecdhe.txt HTTP/1.0

read:errno=104
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a `--sessionid` option for curl or something similar you could use here. It would not make any sense too since the TLS session id (and session token) both refer to internal SSL states from an existing TLS handshake which the curl client does not have.

Comment: They have provided --sessionid in their man page. Please find the snippet.

--no-sessionid
              (SSL) Disable curl's use of SSL session-ID caching.  By default all transfers are done using the cache. Note that while nothing should ever get hurt  by attempting to reuse SSL session-IDs, there seem to be broken SSL implementations in the wild that may require you to disable this in  order for you to succeed. (Added in 7.16.0)
 Note that this is the negated option name documented. You can thus use --sessionid to enforce session-ID caching.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for the help